# Add Custom Header in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, analysis, data-integration

I have data that looks like the following:

### assetnum | assetdesc

123      | sampledesc

432      | sample desc2

I want to insert another row with four fields so it looks like the following:

SYSNAME  | OBJSTRUC | AddChange | En

### assetnum | assetdesc

123      | sampledesc

432      | sample desc2

However I am unsure how to do this. Does anyone know how?
I have tried generating rows but I am unsure how to merge so that it looks like this. I have also thought of adding headers but I am unsure how to specify the header (without it being created automatically) I am quite new to Pentaho. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify where do you have your data with 2 fields and where do you want to insert a row with 4 fields?

Comment: I want to insert the row with 4 fields above where i have the original 2 field names, so as a result the 4 fields will become the new field names

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve in the end. Are you using pentaho data integration aka kettle? If so, then what do you mean by 'header'? Do you want to write the data into a file (CSV or xls) with a header row?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack. Assume `StepA` writes the actual data into a file `fileA`. Before writing anything into your `fileA` have a `Text file output` step and in the `content` tab, `Add Ending line of file` field, enter the custom row you need to insert. Since the file is empty at the beginning, your last line will become the first line. Once it is done, you can write the other data as per your original source using `Append` flag. To set the dependency, use the `Block until steps finish` to block the actual write in `StepA`.